# Is there a way to use collections on the stack in Rust?

Tags: collections, stack, rust

Is there a way to use the collections from Rust's standard library on the stack?  Assume you know in advance an upper bound on the number of items you will want to store in the collection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the implementation of `Vec` (admittedly one of the simplest collections), you will notice:

```
use alloc::heap::{EMPTY, allocate, reallocate, deallocate};
```

Unlike C++, the collections are not *yet* parameterized by an allocator. It is something that is certainly desirable, in the long term, however this was not deemed necessary for 1.0.

If I remember the discussions correctly, some proposals hinged on HKT (Higher Kinded Types) for example, which are not a thing yet.

So, for now, no.